# Rock-Scissors-Paper game - Code does not work

Tags: javascript, html, function

My rock-scissors-paper game is not working.

I am a JavaScript beginner and need your help.

Here is my code:

```js
function user(x) {
  var element_user = document.getElementById('user');
  return element_user.innerHTML = x;
}

function enemy() {
  random_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);

  if (random_number == 1) {
    random_number = "Stein";
  } else if (random_number == 2) {
    random_number = "Schere";
  } else {
    random_number = "Papier";
  }
  var element_enemy = document.getElementById('enemy');
  return element_enemy.innerHTML = random_number;
}    

function winner() {
  if (user() === 'Stein' && random_number === 'Schere') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (user() === 'Stein' && random_number === 'Papier')  {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (user() === 'Schere' && random_number === 'Stein') {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (user() === 'Schere' && random_number === 'Papier') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (user() === 'Papier' && random_number === 'Stein') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (user() === 'Papier' && random_number === 'Schere') {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else {
    return "Unentschieden!";
  }
  var winner_element = document.getElementById('winner');
  winner_element.innerHTML = winner();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>S+S+P</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p id="user"></p>  
  <p id="enemy"></p>
  
  <button onclick="user('Stein'), enemy();">Stein</button>
  <button onclick="user('Schere'), enemy();">Schere</button>
  <button onclick="user('Papier'), enemy();">Papier</button>
  
  <p id="winner"></p>
  
  <button onclick="winner();">Gewinner</button>

<script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. User can click either on rock, scissors or paper;
2. The result of the user is shown above + random choice by my JS program;
3. When you click 'Gewinner', it should show who wins the game.

I'm stuck on #3. The winner doesn't show up.

Thanks,

Josef

Comment: a small hint, after `return`, there is no `else` necessary, just proceed with `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problems

Your `user()` function is not meant to be called without parameters, which you are doing in the `winner()` function.

Let's review the function in detail:

```
function user(x) {
  var element_user = document.getElementById('user');
  return element_user.innerHTML = x;
}
```

1. In the first line you say you expect one argument and give it the name `x`. When you call the function with no parameters, `x` will be undefined.
2. In the second line you are looking for the `#user` element and assigning it to a local variable. This is fine.
3. Now you are doing two things in one line, basically:

   ```
   element_user.innerHTML = x;
   return element_user.innerHTML;
   ```

When you call this function from within `winner()` you are passing no arguments, which makes the innerHTML be `undefined` which is also what you are seeing in the result. Instead of calling the function you can also get the result from the element itself.

A different issue is your call to `winner()` from within `winner()` which will never return because the function is calling itself recursively until it hits a limit and the browser stops it.

## The quick solution

With these two issues fixed, your code looks like this:

```js
function user(x) {
  var element_user = document.getElementById('user');
  return element_user.innerHTML = x;
}

function enemy() {
  random_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);

  if (random_number == 1) {
    random_number = "Stein";
  } else if (random_number == 2) {
    random_number = "Schere";
  } else {
    random_number = "Papier";
  }
  var element_enemy = document.getElementById('enemy');
  return element_enemy.innerHTML = random_number;
}    

function winner() {
  var userChoice = document.getElementById('user').innerHTML;
  console.log(userChoice);
  console.log(random_number);
  if (userChoice === 'Stein' && random_number === 'Schere') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Stein' && random_number === 'Papier')  {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Schere' && random_number === 'Stein') {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Schere' && random_number === 'Papier') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Papier' && random_number === 'Stein') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Papier' && random_number === 'Schere') {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else {
    return "Unentschieden!";
  }
}

function writeResult() {
  var winner_element = document.getElementById('winner');
  winner_element.innerHTML = winner();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>S+S+P</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p id="user"></p>  
  <p id="enemy"></p>
  
  <button onclick="user('Stein'), enemy();">Stein</button>
  <button onclick="user('Schere'), enemy();">Schere</button>
  <button onclick="user('Papier'), enemy();">Papier</button>
  
  <p id="winner"></p>
  
  <button onclick="writeResult();">Gewinner</button>

<script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works, but still has many bugs and smells:

- The functions are badly named and not documented. Their functionality is hard to guess.
- You have global variables leaking out of functions.
- You are mixing German and English...

## Refactoring iteration 1

I've allowed myself to clean up the code a little:

```js
/**
 * Sets the given user choice as html text on the #userOutput element.
 */
function setUserChoice(choice) {
  document.getElementById('userOutput').innerHTML = choice;
}

/**
 * Choses a random choice for the enemy and sets it as html on the
 * #enemyOutput element. Possible outputs are "Stein", "Schere" and "Paper".
 */
function setRandomEnemyChoice() {
  var enemyPossibleChoices = ["Stein", "Schere", "Papier"];
  var enemyChoiceNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var enemyChoice = enemyPossibleChoices[enemyChoiceNum];
  document.getElementById('enemyOutput').innerHTML = enemyChoice;
}    

/**
 * Given two strings where each is one of "Stein", "Schere" or "Paper",
 * determines the winner and returns the result of the match as string.
 */
function determineWinner(userChoice, enemyChoice) {
  if (userChoice === 'Stein' && enemyChoice === 'Schere') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Stein' && enemyChoice === 'Papier')  {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Schere' && enemyChoice === 'Stein') {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Schere' && enemyChoice === 'Papier') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Papier' && enemyChoice === 'Stein') {
    return "User hat gewonnen!";
  } else if (userChoice === 'Papier' && enemyChoice === 'Schere') {
    return "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
  } else {
    return "Unentschieden!";
  }
}

/**
 * Gathers the user and enemy choices, and uses them to determine the
 * result of the match. The result is then written as html to
 * #resultOutput.
 */
function writeResult() {
  var userChoice = document.getElementById('userOutput').innerHTML;
  var enemyChoice = document.getElementById('enemyOutput').innerHTML;
  var resultText = determineWinner(userChoice, enemyChoice);
  document.getElementById('resultOutput').innerHTML = resultText;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>S+S+P</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p id="userOutput"></p>  
  <p id="enemyOutput"></p>
  
  <button onclick="setUserChoice('Stein'); setRandomEnemyChoice();">Stein</button>
  <button onclick="setUserChoice('Schere'); setRandomEnemyChoice();">Schere</button>
  <button onclick="setUserChoice('Papier'); setRandomEnemyChoice();">Papier</button>
  
  <p id="resultOutput"></p>
  
  <button onclick="writeResult();">Gewinner</button>

<script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the method names and IDs are a little more clear. In the next step of refactoring you could introduce better state saving with one global object instead of element-bound strings. The choices should be probably constants with string representations - so you only work with `SCISSORS`, `STONE` and `PAPER` in code and output the German string where required. Then the if..else constructs could be greatly simplified, as others already noted. I'll leave iteration 2 to you :-)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines in the function winner() are never executed because of the returns before that. 
Can you change al the "return ..." into "result = ..." and end with "winner_element.innterHTML = result;" ? Like this:

```
function winner() {
      var result = ""
      if (user() === 'Stein' && random_number === 'Schere') {
        result = "User hat gewonnen!";
      ...
      } else if (user() === 'Papier' && random_number === 'Schere') {
        result = "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
      } else {
        result = "Unentschieden!";
      }
      var winner_element = document.getElementById('winner');
      winner_element.innerHTML = result;
    }
```

Also, the user() function is not right. Change it into something like this:

```
function user() {
  var element_user = document.getElementById('user');
  return element_user.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now the button "Gewinner" is executing the function. I still have the problem, that I always get "Unentschieden" as a result. I also change the user choice to undefined... There is still something wrong.

Comment: Your user() method it not right. Drop the argument to the function and remove the "=x". I edited my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the working code snippet as shown below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>S+S+P</title>
</head>
<body>

 <p id="user"></p>
 <p id="enemy"></p>

 <button onclick="user('Stein'), enemy();">Stein</button>
 <button onclick="user('Schere'), enemy();">Schere</button>
 <button onclick="user('Papier'), enemy();">Papier</button>

 <p id="winner"></p>

 <button onclick="winner();">Gewinner</button>

 <script>
  function user(x) {
   var element_user = document.getElementById('user');
   return element_user.innerHTML = x;
  }

  function enemy() {
   random_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);

   if (random_number == 1) {
    random_number = "Stein";
   } else if (random_number == 2) {
    random_number = "Schere";
   } else {
    random_number = "Papier";
   }
   var element_enemy = document.getElementById('enemy');
   return element_enemy.innerHTML = random_number;
  }

  function winner() {
   var user = document.getElementById('user').innerHTML;
   var winner="";
   if (user === 'Stein' && random_number === 'Schere') {
    winner = "User hat gewonnen!";
   } else if (user === 'Stein' && random_number === 'Papier') {
    winner = "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
   } else if (user === 'Schere' && random_number === 'Stein') {
    winner = "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
   } else if (user === 'Schere' && random_number === 'Papier') {
    winner = "User hat gewonnen!";
   } else if (user === 'Papier' && random_number === 'Stein') {
    winner = "User hat gewonnen!";
   } else if (user === 'Papier' && random_number === 'Schere') {
    winner = "Enemy hat gewonnen!";
   } else {
    winner = "Unentschieden!";
   }
   var winner_element = document.getElementById('winner');
   winner_element.innerHTML = winner;
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry if i change the words to English. I cant understand german?

```js
var element_user = document.getElementById('user');
var element_enemy = document.getElementById('enemy');
var winner_element = document.getElementById('winner');

function user(x) {
  return element_user.innerHTML = x;
}

function enemy() {
  random_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);

  if (random_number == 1) {
    random_number = "Stein";
  } else if (random_number == 2) {
    random_number = "Schere";
  } else {
    random_number = "Papier";
  }
  return element_enemy.innerHTML = random_number;
}    

function checkWinner(user, enemy){
  if (user === enemy) {
    return "Its a tie";
  }

  if(user === "Stein"){
      if(enemy === "Papier"){
        return "Enemy wins";
      }
      return "User wins";
  }

  if(user === "Papier"){
      if(enemy === "Stein"){
          return "User wins";
      }
      return "Enemy wins";
  }

  if(user === "Schere"){
     if(enemy === "Stein"){
        return "Enemy wins";
     }

     return "User wins";
  }
}

function winner() {
  var user = element_user.innerHTML;
  var enemy = element_enemy.innerHTML;
  winner_element.innerHTML = checkWinner(user, enemy);
}
```

```html
 <p id="user"></p>  
  <p id="enemy"></p>
  
  <button onclick="user('Stein'), enemy();">Stein</button>
  <button onclick="user('Schere'), enemy();">Schere</button>
  <button onclick="user('Papier'), enemy();">Papier</button>
  
  <p id="winner"></p>
  
  <button onclick="winner();">Gewinner</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's it! Sorry, for the german words. Next time I'll poste code with english words here!